# How I can zoom out using RealityKit?

Tags: swift, camera, zooming, arkit, realitykit

I am using RealityKit for a human body detection.

```
        let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

A person always need stay too far in front of that back camera, more than 4 m. Can I apply a negative zoom? If I use a system camera application I see that a person can stay only 3 m front in.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't zoom out sadly with reality kit. Reality kit uses the camera provided by ARKit and it's fixed with a focal length of 28mm.